Как реализовать скачивание бекпапа?
В S3 хранится бекап нескольких сервисов Яндекса. Каждый сервис хранится в отдельной папке, метаданные о файлах хранятся в базе данных. Нужно реализовать скачивание через fastapi так, чтобы файлы присылались по мере их скачивания из s3, возможно ли такое, если да, то как это реализовать?

1 - можно дать прямую ссылку на скачивание с s3, чтобы вообще свой сервер не нагружать лишней работой. 2 - или делаете streaming response, по мере получения данных возвращаете их через yield.
